# Simultanous read and write queries to a MySQL table (Wordpress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a "Table A" in a MySQL database as part of my Wordpress solution.

- Whilst inserting data into that table I assume the table is locked,
  correct?
- What happens if users are executing read queries (select statements) during this insert?
- Furthermore, what happens in case there are multiple simultaneous
  inserts?

I understand that this is not a syntax question but I will choose the design depending on the answer.

Comment: I know it's not light reading, but you may want to consult the documentation for [MySQL locks][https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html] . There's an [easier read here](https://hevodata.com/learn/mysql-locks/)